# How to make a Discord.js bot read and use image urls which have been sent in chat

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am making a bot which will check if a message **contains** an image link matches a preset image list, and so it responds accordingly!

e.g.

```
User1: This is an image: discordapp.com/attachments/test123test123
Bot: That image is of blank!
```

If someone tells me the function which gets image urls it would be great! It would be even more useful if someone could show me how to apply this by checking the URL against a preset list which will name what the image is of!
Cheers!

Comment: if I understand right, you want your bot to check every message to see if there is a link to an image, right, and try to match it with a list you already have?
Specific url? (like only discord link image, or any link, like google, imgur etc)

Comment: @JackRed yes, however only messages from a specific user will be scanned (only 1 user) and all other messages will be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Its EZ**

```js
message.channel.send(message.attachments.first().url)
```

Comment: Its just an example to get the attachment url.

Comment: What would you recommend to do in order to check it against a list and reply based on what it matched with in the list?

Comment: you mean to compare?

Comment: Yes. To compare against a preset list of links.

Comment: this is a hard thing to do, but you can compare the attachment.width and the attachments.size

Comment: What I'm trying to do here is that when a Discord bot called Pokécord spawns a pokemon in (by making an embed with an image of the pokemon) and then grab the link of that image, then compare it against a set of links. I'm 99% sure they all use the same width and size.

Comment: I really don't know about how to compare the whole image with another one, but FYI the image can be smaller than the one on the list, so you can't say you're sure.

Comment: True. Thanks so much for your help!